# Select Information from MySql table then store this into a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySql table, and I want to take a users email from it where a user id is given to pin point the information. I want to then get this email, store it in a variable and then use it to email someone inside the script.

Heres my code so far but it does not display:

```
<

?php

$appid = $_POST["appid"];
$option1 = $_POST['radio'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "mcxjb";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "members1";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_level='$option1' WHERE userid=$appid";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Success!";
} else {
    echo "Error " . mysqli_error($conn);
}


$emailsql = "SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE userid=$appid";

$query = mysql_query($emailsql);


mysqli_close($conn);



?>
```

The script allows the user to approve or deny a person application. It then updates that users user level to approved or denied. I then want to email the user by extracting their email by using their userid that was given and take it from the SQL table !

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: So... what is the result of this code, and if you get an error what is it, give more information

Comment: Hey, it runs the update of the sql table and nothing else. Im not sure if I could echo the result of the select to see if it has worked?

Comment: Try this : var_dump($query); before mysqli_close($conn); what is the output ?

Comment: Did that and instead of getting the success message for the update I just got a complete blank browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your update query you need to change this :

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))..
```

Whit this :

```
if(mysqli_query($sql))...
```

And to access the result of your select query you need to do it like this :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {    

          //access Email using $row['email_address']
            // use PHP mail function here

        }
```

So the code will be :

```
<?php

$appid = $_POST["appid"];
$option1 = $_POST['radio'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "mcxjb";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "members1";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_level='$option1' WHERE userid=$appid";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Success!";
} else {
    echo "Error " . mysqli_error($conn);
}


$emailsql = "SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE userid=$appid";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $emailsql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {    

              //access Email using $row['email_address']
                // use PHP mail function here

            }

mysqli_close($conn);



?>
```

Comment: I used that and email code, but it just gives me Error displayed in the browser, which is from the Update.

Comment: This is what comes up [link](http://www.markbarrettdesign.com/staffapplication/status.php)

Comment: Add var_dump($conn); after you connect to the database and tell me what contains this object

Comment: Its too big to put here but you can see it here [link](http://www.markbarrettdesign.com/staffapplication/status.php)

Comment: So it means you are connected successfully to the database, now you need to check the update query, you are sure that the fields are correct (the table users is correct and user_lever and the userid names are the same in the database ?) and also what is the type of user_level and userid ? Int, varchar,... or what?

Comment: Yes, all the fields are correct. When I use if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) it updates the information correctly, however the SELECT isn't working and when I change it back to (mysqli_query($sql)) it gives me the "Error". As for the information, the user_level is enum, and the userid is int.

Comment: Humm, so use your syntax to update and do the same to the select query (mysqli_query($conn, $emailsql))

Comment: I changed the SELECT query to that, so that they were both the same, then to check I changed both to what you said originally (mysqli_query($sql)) and it still isn't working. There is no error in the browser just a blank window.

Comment: Aah i don't see it before check the syntax you have for select (mysql_query...) not (mysqli_query...) try to fix it and use both parameters $conn and the sql query take a look to my answer i updated it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iLAN8m9D Thats what I have, and the update works perfectly, just still ignores the email.

Comment: Try what i said in my last answer before this comment

Comment: My good sir that did it :)! Thank you very much, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcom thanks to you too i learned how to use mysqli update and select ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {    

          //access Email using $row['email_address']
            // use PHP mail function here

        }
```